# Adicionar método a uma classe c++ existente

Tags: c++, método

Gostaria de saber se no c++ tem como incrementar uma classe existente inserindo novos métodos, sem mexer diretamente no código fonte da classe.

Por exemplo, se a classe abaixo for parte de uma biblioteca externa que não deve ser alterada, contendo 2 métodos:

```
class original
{
public:
    void metodo1() {
        std::cout << "método 1" << endl;
    }
    void metodo2() {
        std::cout << "método 2" << endl;
    }
};
```

Então dentro de meu código, eu gostaria de incrementar esta classe inserido um terceiro método:

```
void metodo3() {
    std::cout << "método 3" << endl;
}
```

Como seria isso possível?

Comment: Não dá para extender a classe sem modificar a própria classe.  No entanto, há uma série de estratégias e boas-práticas que podem e devem ser usadas em casos como essse, como o princípio Open/Close. Uma estratégia popular consiste em recorrer a funções  que aceitem a classe como parâmetro (ver padrões de desenho de software tipo Factory, Strategy, ou Command) ou conceber a classe já a pensar na sua extensão (padrão de desenho de software tipo Visitor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é possível fazer isso sem alterar o código da classe, é necessário que você coloque pelo menos o nome da função na classe. Daria pra resolver o seu exemplo da seguinte forma:

```
class original
{
public:
    void metodo1() {
        std::cout << "método 1" << endl;
    }
    void metodo2() {
        std::cout << "método 2" << endl;
    }
    void metodo3();
};
```

O método 3 :

```
void original::metodo3(){
    std::cout << "método 3" << endl;
}
```

Ou você pode criar uma nova classe e herdar todo o conteúdo da classe original:

```
class copia : public original{
public:

void metodo3(){
    std::cout << "método 3" << endl;
}

};
```

Comment: Obrigado! Apenas não entendi a parte do `original::void metodo3()`, pelo menos aqui deu erro de compilação `expected unqualified-id before 'void'`.